# My use of StatusBar in BottomTabNavigator did not work

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

After you switch tabs in the BottomTabNavigator, the statusBar cannot be updated

https://snack.expo.dev/@bbbtt04/my-use-of-statusbar-in-bottomtabnavigator-did-not-work

This is an example of running at expo, asking the big guy to help ,I'm really upset

After you switch tabs in the BottomTabNavigator, the statusBar needs to be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StatusBar` updates only at the time of rendering.

So, whenever you switch between tabs you need to re-render your `StatusBar` for the `backgroundColor` to get updated.

You can do this by using the `useIsFocused` hook.

```js
    import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
    
    function HomeScreen() {
      const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          {isFocused ? <StatusBar backgroundColor={'white'} /> : null}
          <Text>Home!</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Same handling will be done in `SettingsScreen()`.

Basically, this will re-render your `StatusBar` whenever your selected Tab is in focus. You can read more about `useIsFocused()` from [here.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/)